# Can out and ref be used as temporary variables?

Tags: c#, .net

When we use **out** or **ref** inside calculations, with multiple assignments and reading from it, what drawbacks does it have? Will it hurt performance?

```
static bool TrySomeFunction(int x, int y, out int result)
{
    result = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        result += result + x;
        if (result == y)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or should we better be using additional variable:

```
static bool TrySomeFunction(int x, int y, out int result)
    {
        int temp = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            temp += temp + x;
            if (temp == y)
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }      
        }
        result = temp;
        return true;
    }
```

Update: changed function name from SomeFunction to make it more clear for intended use.

Comment: I guess the only way to find out is using a profiler. The generated IL code will be almost identical (except for the use of ldloc vs ldarg), but the JIT compiler might do some optimizations that are hard to predict.

Comment: Profiling really is the only way, especially since these functions may end up inlined. Which one then ends up being "best" depends on your scenario. For example, the second function might generate shorter/better assembler "on its own", but the first could be optimized better if fed constant `x` or `y`. As always, premature optimization is the root of all evil; first just write the function in the manner that seems most obvious to you. (Also note that, even if the intent is that `result` is not used if the function returns `false`, these functions may not have the same output.)

Comment: Interesting, but these functions do different things. 1. when the sum is equal to `y` the `result` is also equal to `y`. 2. when the sum is equal to `y`, the result is equal to `0`.

Comment: Another option, return a Tuple `(bool, int)` instead of using `out` and `ref`, [Tuple Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples). [Performance of Value Tuples](https://ladeak.wordpress.com/2018/06/16/performance-of-value-tuples-in-c-2/)

Comment: *what drawbacks does it have?* - it overwrites the calling method's supplied argument with some temporary, potentially-invalid-at-some-random-moment garbage. Don't use out/ref unless absolutely necessary. Your example doesn't really qualify as "absolutely necessary" IMHO

Comment: *Can out and ref..* - "can" is usually "yes"; "should" is perhaps the better question :)

Comment: @E. Shcherbo Well, yes, they do different things, but only when function return false - so in quesion assumed than in this case result is invalid anyway.

Comment: @quaabaam Tuples are great, but Try something is nice way to declutter some cases. Changed function name to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the more calculations we do the more the difference between the performance of both.

I believe this is expected, since here we see an extra level of indirection. [ldind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc?view=net-6.0) and [stind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc?view=net-6.0) operations used to get/set the value for `out` parameter (indirectly) and [ldoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc?view=net-6.0) with [stloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stloc?view=net-6.0) used to get/set values for local variables.

I think that compiler can't do any optimizations here (at least convert `UseOutExtensively` to `DontUseOutExtensively`), because this might change the behavior of the method if some other thread writes to the location of `out` parameter at the same time the function is executed.

#### Test

Let me a bit simplify your function so that we concentrate on what we're interested in only:

```
void UseOutExtensively(out int result)
{
    result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int temp = result;
        result = temp;
    }
}

void DontUseOutExtensively(out int result)
{
    int temp = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int anotherTemp = temp;
        temp = anotherTemp;
    }
    result = temp;
}
```

So the functions don't do anything useful, they just swap the same value between the variables. Thus we don't have complex additions and conditions, only get/set an `out` variable and get/set a local variable.

So the test program is the following:

```
int Iterations = 10000000; // we'll try 10^7, 10^8 && 10^9

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
  UseOutExtensively(out int result);

Console.WriteLine("Using out extensively: {0}",
                          sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
  DontUseOutExtensively(out int result);

Console.WriteLine("Don't use out extensively: {0}",
                          sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Results:

| Iterations | UseOutExtensively | DontUseOutExtensively |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10^7 | 918 | 330 |
| 10^8 | 8850 | 3331 |
| 10^9 | 92009 | 34823 |

We see the more operations we perform the more the difference in performance is noticeable.

Comment: Did you do your test runs in debug or release mode?

Comment: I tested in release mode

Answer (score 4):

> Will it hurt performance?

There is a very slight performance difference, yes. The IL compiler and the JIT compiler can optimize *a lot* of things here. For example, taking [E. Shcherbo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71356881/120955) `UseOutExtensively` method, the x64 instructions without any optimizations looks like this:

```
L0000   push    rbp
L0001   sub rsp, 0x30
L0005   lea rbp, [rsp+0x30]
L000a   xor eax, eax
L000c   mov [rbp-0xc], rax
L0010   mov [rbp-4], eax
L0013   mov [rbp+0x10], rcx
L0017   mov [rbp+0x18], rdx
L001b   cmp dword ptr [0x7ff84f32c2f0], 0
L0022   je  short L0029
L0024   call    0x00007ff8adecca10
L0029   nop 
L002a   mov rax, [rbp+0x18]
L002e   xor edx, edx
L0030   mov [rax], edx
L0032   mov [rbp-4], edx
L0035   nop 
L0036   jmp short L0054
L0038   nop 
L0039   mov rax, [rbp+0x18]
L003d   mov eax, [rax]
L003f   mov [rbp-8], eax
L0042   mov rax, [rbp+0x18]
L0046   mov edx, [rbp-8]
L0049   mov [rax], edx
L004b   nop 
L004c   mov eax, [rbp-4]
L004f   inc eax
L0051   mov [rbp-4], eax
L0054   cmp dword ptr [rbp-4], 0x64
L0058   setl    al
L005b   movzx   eax, al
L005e   mov [rbp-0xc], eax
L0061   cmp dword ptr [rbp-0xc], 0
L0065   jne short L0038
L0067   nop 
L0068   add rsp, 0x30
L006c   pop rbp
L006d   ret
```

Whereas with optimizations enabled, it looks like this:

```
L0000   xor eax, eax
L0002   mov [rdx], eax
L0004   mov ecx, [rdx]
L0006   mov [rdx], ecx
L0008   inc eax
L000a   cmp eax, 0x64
L000d   jl  short L0004
L000f   ret
```

`DontUseOutExtensively`, on the other hand, looks like this when optimized.

```
L0000   xor eax, eax
L0002   inc eax
L0004   cmp eax, 0x64
L0007   jl  short L0002
L0009   mov dword ptr [rdx], 8
L000f   ret
```

Notice how one thing that couldn't be optimized when using an `out` variable is the `mov` instructions. When using a temporary variable, the compiler can keep everything in Control Registers, which are used for math operations. Setting and accessing `out` variables have to move these values to and from Debug Registers, which takes a little more time.

Plugging those functions into [some benchmarking LINQPad code](http://share.linqpad.net/c4f9lg.linq) I have on hand, you can see there's a measurable difference in performance as a result, which confirms the results E. Shcherbo noted.

[image]

However, that's an extremely contrived case. In something even slightly more complicated like your original code, the difference becomes far less pronounced.

[image]

At any rate, you're talking about a difference of milliseconds over millions of iterations, so worrying about which of these approaches to take for performance reasons is almost certainly a premature optimization.

> what drawbacks does it have?

Ignoring performance, you should definitely think about how the *behavior* of your code is impacted by this decision.

Let's say your function threw an exception, for example: would you want the value of `result` to have been changed in the output, even though no value was returned?

Or what if the value of the variable passed as your `out` parameter is being read by other threads? Do you want that variable's value to change as the function executes? Maybe you're using that variable to track the progress of your function's execution, in which case there's value to changing the value as you go. But if not, it's probably "tidier" to avoid changing the `out` variable until you've got a corresponding return value to go with it.

On that note, why use an `out` parameter at all? You could use a ValueTuple, [as suggested by quaabaam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356352/can-out-and-ref-be-used-as-temporary-variables#comment126128432_71356352), or just a `Nullable<>` return value. These approaches make your function *pure*, which makes it more friendly to multi-threaded operations, LINQ expression syntax, lambda expressions, and so forth, with similar performance to the temporary variable approach.

[image]

[LINQPad Benchmark](http://share.linqpad.net/bdqnts.linq)

```
static (bool Found, int Result) SomeFunctionValueTuple(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        temp += temp + x;
        if (temp == y)
        {
            return (false, 0);
        }
    }
    return (true, temp);
}
```

```
static int? SomeFunctionNullable(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        temp += temp + x;
        if (temp == y)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why out parameter makes function impure - it pretty much guaranteed that we write at least something in it?  _> On that note, why use an out parameter at all? You could use a ValueTuple, as suggested by quaabaam, or just a Nullable<> return value. These approaches make your function pure._

Comment: @PavelIvanov `out` parameter indicates that the variable will be assigned, but this also means that the function has a side effect, right? Moreover, in multithreading world this might give different results with the same arguments. Thus 2 requirements of pure function aren't met.